# I cant make the textfile appear to my JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse, jtextarea, filereader

This is my first time to post a question. So please be friendly.

I'm having trouble with my java program which is the textfile can't appear in my `JTextArea`, I'm using `Eclipse Luna`.

Here is my program :

```
public class Frame_Cashier extends JFrame {
    String[] category = {"Breakfast","Drinks","Add-ons","Desserts","Happy Meal","Value Meal"};
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(category);
    private JPanel contentPane;
    JTextArea txtrItemId;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame_Cashier frame = new Frame_Cashier();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Frame_Cashier(){

        Container c = getContentPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 759, 469);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(new Color(178, 34, 34));
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 752, 21);
        contentPane.add(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        mnFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        mnFile.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        mnFile.setBackground(new Color(255, 69, 0));
        mnFile.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 15));
        JMenuItem transaction = new JMenuItem("Transaction");
        transaction.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        transaction.setBackground(new Color(178, 34, 34));
        transaction.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        JMenuItem logout = new JMenuItem("Logout");
        logout.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        logout.setBackground(new Color(178, 34, 34));
        logout.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        menuBar.add(mnFile);
        mnFile.add(transaction);
        mnFile.add(logout);

        JLabel img_background = new JLabel("");
        img_background.setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 0));

        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("cashier_img.jpg")).getImage();

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3, true));
        textArea.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        textArea.setBounds(380, 32, 353, 280);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        JTextArea txtrItemId = new JTextArea();
        txtrItemId.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        txtrItemId.setToolTipText("Item ID / Item Name");
        txtrItemId.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        txtrItemId.setBounds(20, 114, 119, 150);
        txtrItemId.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(txtrItemId);

        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(5);
        comboBox.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        comboBox.setBounds(20, 61, 338, 21);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);

        JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_2.setEditable(false);
        textArea_2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        textArea_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        textArea_2.setBounds(175, 114, 72, 150);
        contentPane.add(textArea_2);

        JTextArea textArea_3 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_3.setEditable(false);
        textArea_3.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        textArea_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        textArea_3.setBounds(273, 114, 72, 150);
        contentPane.add(textArea_3);

        JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        textArea_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        textArea_1.setBounds(63, 290, 119, 22);
        contentPane.add(textArea_1);

        JTextArea txtrNoImage = new JTextArea();
        txtrNoImage.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        txtrNoImage.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3, true));
        txtrNoImage.setText("No Image");
        txtrNoImage.setBounds(202, 274, 144, 126);
        contentPane.add(txtrNoImage);

        JLabel lblPrice = new JLabel("Price");
        lblPrice.setForeground(new Color(255, 204, 51));
        lblPrice.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblPrice.setBounds(281, 89, 64, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblPrice);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Stock");
        lblNewLabel_3.setForeground(new Color(255, 204, 51));
        lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(186, 89, 48, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Item ID / Item Name");
        lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(new Color(255, 204, 51));
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(10, 89, 157, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Item I.D");
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(new Color(255, 204, 0));
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(0, 290, 64, 22);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Select Category");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 204, 0));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 32, 134, 31);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Void");
        btnNewButton_1.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);
        btnNewButton_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        btnNewButton_1.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
        btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 13));
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(634, 340, 99, 31);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Pay");
        btnNewButton.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 15));
        btnNewButton.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
        btnNewButton.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(380, 340, 99, 31);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Edit");
        btnNewButton_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        btnNewButton_2.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);
        btnNewButton_2.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD, 13));
        btnNewButton_2.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(513, 340, 89, 31);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);

        img_background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        img_background.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        img_background.setBounds(0, 21, 752, 410);
        contentPane.add(img_background);

        combohandler1 ch1 = new combohandler1();
        comboBox.addActionListener(ch1);
    }

    private class combohandler1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6; 
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Breakfast")){
                try{
                        FileReader file = new FileReader("breakfast.txt");

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

                        item1 = br.readLine();
                        item2 = br.readLine();
                        item3 = br.readLine();
                        item4 = br.readLine();
                        item5 = br.readLine();

                        System.out.println("test.txt");
                        txtrItemId.setText("\n"+item1+"\n"+item2+"\n"+item3+"\n"+item4+"\n"+item5+"\n");

                        br.close();
                    }catch(Exception x){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to find");               
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code sample to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we will be more likely and able to help.

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: If there is an exception, it appears to be caught and lost. Instead a `JOptionPane` is shown with the message "Unable to find".  @Angelo Maniego In the `catch` block, please add something like `x.printStackTrace()` and see if an exception appears on the console when running.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the text area twice, once locally in the constructor and once globally

you will be getting a `nullPointerException` at `txtrItemId.setText();`

change : `JTextArea txtrItemId = new JTextArea();`

to: `txtrItemId = new JTextArea();`

When you try to access `txtrItemId` in your event handler, you are accessing the one that is declared globally where as you have initialized the variable declared in the constructor, the scope of this variable(declared in the constructor) will be limited only to that method/constructor.